# Is a svn repository browse-able (or should it be)?

Tags: svn

I've created a SVN server on a windows computer (using win32svn).  In that location I created multiple directories (ProjA, ProjB, etc), then using TortoiseSVN I created repositories in some of those directories and imported code to those repositories.  Lets say the server is on the computer \EARTH.

My question is, should a developer be able to "browse" those repositories?  As it is now, if you don't know the name of the repository (like "ProjA"), you don't see anything.  If I open the Tortoise Repository Browser and point it to svn://earth you get an error message saying there is no repository there.  And I agree, there isn't one.

Should a user be able to go to svn://earth and see there are other locations like svn://earth/proja, etc?

Maybe to put this another way: should I be doing something to "publish" the availability of the different repositories?

Answer (score 1):

The repositories are a set of directories with the repository data. The data itself is held in a database file below `db`, configuration below `conf`, hooks below `hooks` etc; this structure exists per repository. There is no "super" structure (collections of repositories) above single repositories in SVN. If you want to allow such you need to configure a server that provides this. Typically this is an Apache Web server that is configured to provide the repositories via WebDAV / HTTP. Easiest on Windows in my opinion is [Visual SVN](http://www.visualsvn.com/server/) but it is possible to do the setup manually, of course.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using Apache httpd as your Subversion server?

What you need to do is add in the `SVNListParentPath on` into your httpd configuration. On Unix, try `/etc/httpd/conf.d/subversion.conf`. On Windows, I have no idea where it could be. Look under the `C:\Program Files` directory for *Apache* or `httpd`.

An example on how to configure this can be found [here](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.serverconfig.httpd.html#svn.serverconfig.httpd.extra.browsing.xslt):

```
<Location /svn>
  DAV svn
  SVNParentPath /var/svn
  SVNListParentPath on
  …
</Location>
```

With this, if you go to `http://earth/svn`, it will list all of the repositories in your Subversion parent repository directory. This will work in either Tortoise or in a web browser.

By the way, if you need a web browsing tool for Subversion, take a look at [Sventon](http://sventon.org).